# Problem using Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.GenericAttributeProfile reference

Tags: c#, bluetooth

I am trying to use the C# library `GattCharacteristic` and I'm having trouble with references. I used Nuget to get the UwpDesktop package which was a suggestion posted elsewhere.

> 'Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.GenericAttributeProfile.GattCharacteristic' in assembly 'Windows' causes a cycle.

> The type name 'GattCharacteristic' could not be found in the namespace 'Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.GenericAttributeProfile'. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'Windows, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime' Consider adding a reference to that assembly.

I've also tried adding the `windows.winmd` reference and adding `<TargetPlatformVersion>10.0</TargetPlatformVersion>` to the .csproj file with no success.

Comment: Every hardware device in windows has a header with parameters.  When the drive installs the device the drive reads the header.  You can see some of this info when you use Device Manager.  The parameters for each device vary and it is up to manufacture to decide what parameters to use.  The are some window requirements like type of device (disk, usb, serial port).  Make sure you use the vendor drivers with each device and not a generic driver which may not be able to read some of the device parameters which are not always in the header.

Comment: How can I find out which hardware driver is the problem?

Comment: The one for the bluetooth device that is not working. You can enumerate through all devices and see what info is available for each device.

Comment: @jdwen: that is absolutely not related to any hadrware. It is simple assembl linking issue. This could help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance

Comment: Or you can use third-party libraries such 32feet or Bluetooth Framework

Comment: I tried the `Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts` install and adding `TargetFramework` to the .csproj file and still making my way through that link you sent